# Plotting Pandas into subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

da is my dataframe. I want to make this figure into one subplot out of 2 that I will have. When I add plt.subplots(2,1,2) for this figure it ends up separating this figure into a separate figure and the subplot is an empty figure.

How can I make this code into a subplot?

-Thank you in advance, I am a newbie in python. 
 [image]

```
ax1 = da.plot(rot = 90, title ='Pre-Folsom Dam Spring Recession')
ax1.set_xlabel('Water Year Day')
ax1.axhline( y = float(fSP_Mag) , xmin=0, xmax=35,color ='r', linestyle='--',zorder=0,label= 'Magnitude')
ax1.axvline(x=float(fSP_Tim), color ='r',linestyle='--', label='Timing')
ax1.legend(framealpha=1, frameon=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4,5],"col2":[2,4,6,8,10]})
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
data["col1"].plot(ax=ax1)
data["col2"].plot(ax=ax2)
```

Create a plt.figure() and assign subplots to ax1 and ax2.Now plot the dataframe using these axes.

Reference:-

1. [Pyplot](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/how-pandas-uses-matplotlib-plus-figures-axes-and-subplots/)