# Subplotting of Pandas.DataFrameGroupBy[group_name] does not yield expected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

This is a re-opening of my initial question [with the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994817/subplots-with-pandas-dataframe-andgroupby) which was closed as duplicate. As None of the suggested duplicates helped me to solve my problem, I post this question again.

I have a DataFrame with time series related to some devices which come from a hdf-file:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


def open_dataset(file_name: str, name: str, combined_frame: DataFrame):

data_set: DataFrame = pd.read_hdf(file_name, key=name)
data_set['name'] = name
combined_frame = pd.concat([combined_frame, data_set], axis=0)
return combined_frame


if __name__ == '__main__':

    names = ['YRT1IN1E', 'YRT1LE1', 'YRT1MH1', 'YR08DT1ML']

    working_frame = DataFrame()

    for name in names:
        working_frame = open_dataset('data.h5', name, working_frame)

    grouped_frame = working_frame.groupby('name')


    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5),
                        nrows=4, ncols=1,  # fix as above
                        gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0), sharex=True)

    axs = grouped_frame.get_group('YR08DT1ML').rawsum.plot()
    axs = grouped_frame.get_group('YRT1LE1').voltage.plot()
    axs = grouped_frame.get_group('YRT1MH1').current.plot()
    axs = grouped_frame.get_group('YRT1IN1E').current.plot()

    plt.show()
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I would like to have each of the plots in it's own row, not all in one row.

The data file "data.h5" is available at: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T733uy1c7yEcT1oJk6oNhgKy5uBhVWF-/view?usp=sharing)

What I tried from the suggested posts:

[Answer by joris, Mar 18, 2014 at 15:45](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22484249/1552080) causes code to go into infinite loop, data is never plotted:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
grouped_frame.get_group('YR08DT1ML').rawsum.plot(ax=axs[0,0])
grouped_frame.get_group('YR...').rawsum.plot(ax=axs[0,1])
grouped_frame.get_group('YR...').rawsum.plot(ax=axs[1,0])
grouped_frame.get_group('YR...').rawsum.plot(ax=axs[1,1])
```

A variation is leading to same result as I described above:

```
axes[0,0] = grouped_frame.get_group('YR08DT1ML').rawsum.plot()
axes[0,1] = grouped_frame.get_group('YR...').rawsum.plot()
...
```

Infinite loop happens as well for [sedeh's, Jun 4, 2015 at 15:26](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647987/1552080) answer:

```
grouped_frame.get_group('YR08DT1ML').rawsum.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1,2))
...
```

Infinite loop happens as well for [Justice_Lords, Mar 15, 2019 at 7:26](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55177562/1552080) answer:

```
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(4,1,1)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(4,1,2)
ax3=fig.add_subplot(4,1,3)
ax4=fig.add_subplot(4,1,4)

grouped_frame.get_group('YR08DT1ML').rawsum.plot(ax=ax1)
...
```

It seems to me that the problem is related to the fact that I plot with a `pandas.DataFrameGroupBy` and not a `pandas.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like matplotlib was taking a long time to process the DatetimeIndex. Converting to a time and cleaning everything up did the trick:

```
names = ['YR08DT1ML', 'YRT1LE1', 'YRT1MH1', 'YRT1IN1E']
df = pd.concat([pd.read_hdf('data.h5', name) for name in names])

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.index = df['time'].dt.time
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5), nrows=4, ncols=1, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0), sharex=True)

cols = ['rawsum', 'voltage', 'current', 'current']

for ix, name in enumerate(names):
    df.loc[df['nomen'].eq(name), cols[ix]]\
        .plot(ax=axes[ix])

plt.show();
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Did you try to get a full example running with my code + data? I don't get it to work, I only get a plot with four empty lanes. As well I don't understand, why the aggregate function is needed, where I'd like to plot the raw data. Sorry, as it seems I need to boost my DataFrame skills a bit ;)

Comment: There were a bunch of little things so not summarizing but hopefully the functional code above helps. Sorry for posting slightly untested code earlier ;)

Comment: that definitively helped - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fishmulch's answer I found a way to do what I wanted. However, I want to provide an answer for my initial question how to plot the "groupby" data set. The following `__main__` function provides the desired output with input file `data.h5`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['YRT1IN1E', 'YRT1LE1', 'YRT1MH1', 'YR08DT1ML']

    working_frame = DataFrame()
    for name in names:
        working_frame = open_dataset('data.h5', name, working_frame)

    grouped_frame = working_frame.groupby('name')

    fig = plt.figure(1)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1)
    gs.update(wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)  # set the spacing between axes.

    cols = ['current', 'voltage', 'current', 'rawsum']

    row = 0
    for name, col in zip(names, cols):
        data = grouped_frame.get_group(name)
        if row == 0:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[row])
        else:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[row], sharex=ax)
        ax.plot(data.get(col))
        row += 1

    plt.show()
```

[image: Output image]

... some beautification still needed ...